# How to run command as administrator?

Tags: 16.04

In terminal, I find this and it does not respond well to my orders, what should I do?

> To run a command as administrator (user "root"), 
>   use "`sudo <command>`". 
>   See "`man sudo_root`" for details.

This message is found in the beginning of terminal.

Comment: if any command needs to be executed as root, use `sudo` word before the command. like `sudo mv file1 file2`

Comment: Perhaps this will help: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Usage

Comment: What command? Please [edit] your question and give us a specific example so we can understand better.

Answer (score 3):

Just use `sudo <command>`, where *command* is the order, or instruction you want to run as superuser. If you get an error like:

```
user is not in the sudoers file
```

You must edit the /etc/sudoers file. To do so, type

```
su
```

Enter the root password

Then, you can use `nano` or `vi` to edit the file, for example:

```
nano /etc/sudoers
```

Look for a line like this:

```
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

And add a new line bellow this, like:

```
myUser    ALL=(ALL)     ALL
```

Now, reboot your computer, and then try to use sudo.

Regards.